# The meaning 言われる人ってもっと言われてるし

Tags: grammar

From "Skip and Loafer":

[image]
[image]

Frankly speaking, I have no idea what this is supposed to mean, except that I guess "言われて" here refers to being confessed to or something like that? I also wonder if this ties in with the meaning of the sentence, but why is one 言われる and the other 言われ**て**る?

Comment: I think it means "I am mostly called by others as 'a person who often gets talked to'" Sorry for my awkward translation.

Comment: 言われる might refer to 連絡先を聞かれる 告白される. But I need the previous page to understand the situation.

Comment: Okay I just edited my post and added the previous page, though I don't think it will add much to the context. Btw, what do you think about Jimmy Yang's interpretation above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

言われてる means 連絡先を聞かれる or 告白される(you can't decide which is suitable, but there is not so much difference in meaning here.)

So the sentence means 連絡先を聞かれている人は自分よりもっと聞かれている(those who is asked for contact information are asked it more than me),or 告白されてる人は自分よりもっと告白されている(those who is confessed the love are confessed more than me.)