# Is "言われてる" by itself some kind of expression?

Tags: passive-voice

> おまえ、言われてるぞ

> もっともだな

The character got dismissed by someone else in a mean way, so the third person says to him  "おまえ、言われてるぞ" to which the character himself replies "もっともだな"

Is this an expression similar to "You got told" in english?

Answer (score 2):

If 'you got told' means 'now you shut up' as explained in [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/you-got-told.571405/), 言われてる here does not have such an implication.

言われてる means rather literally 'being said/told' with the object omitted. The usage in the following question is similar.

- [The meaning 言われる人ってもっと言われてるし](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/98412/45489)

In the particular context, the omitted object is those dismissing things about the character who says もっともだな. Roughly translated,

- You are being spoken ill of.
- I agree (with what's said about me).

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, but I think it really does mean something like "You got told".
iwareru is the passive form of iu (he/she was affected unfavorably by the harsh words), so iwareteiru is indeed grammatical...